# jquery noty on close goto a url

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using the jquery noty plugin and when someone clicks the popup, i want it to goto a URL (below) but i cant figure this out... can someone give me a quick fix.. ?

URL i want it to goto: script.php?hidenoty=true

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function generate(layout) {
    var n = noty({
        text: "<?php echo $motd?>",
        type: 'warning',
        dismissQueue: true,
        layout: layout,
        theme: 'defaultTheme',
        animation: {
        open: {height: 'toggle'},
        close: {height: 'toggle'},
        easing: 'swing',
        speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
        },
        timeout: false, // delay for closing event. Set false for sticky notifications
        force: false, // adds notification to the beginning of queue when set to true
        modal: false,
        maxVisible: 3, // you can set max visible notification for dismissQueue true option
        closeWith: ['click'], // ['click', 'button', 'hover']
        callback: {
        onShow: function() {},
        afterShow: function() {},
        onClose: function() {
        $.ajax({ url: 'script.php?hidenoty=true' });
        },
        afterClose: function() {}
        },
        buttons: false // an array of buttons
    });
        console.log('html: '+n.options.id);
  }

  function generateAll() {
    generate('topCenter');
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

        generateAll();

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line...

```
$.ajax({ url: 'script.php?hidenoty=true' });
```

to this...

```
window.location.href = 'script.php?hidenoty=true';
```

`ajax` is used specifically to load something *without* changing the page, so the opposite of what you want :)